# Could not load Boto3's S3 bindings

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I'm deploying to Heroku a Django==2.1.2 and Python==3.6.5 app and i would to manage media and static files with Amazon S3.

Here's my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'storages',
)

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '****'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' %  AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_files_storage.StaticFilesStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIAFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_files_storage.MediaFilesStorage'
```

Here's my custom_files_storage.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaFilesStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION

class StaticFilesStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

I have runed:

```
pip install boto

pip install boto3

pip install django-storges
```

I have tried with boto and boto3 but the error keeps

Here's the error output:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py" in <module>
  32.     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Could not load Boto3's S3 bindings.\n"

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /registro/
Exception Value: Could not load Boto3's S3 bindings.
See https://github.com/boto/boto3
```

I don't know how to fix it
Someone could help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding 'boto3' package and version to pipfile (run pipenv lock) and then push to Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to first pip freeze a new requirements.txt file with boto3, and commit before pushing to heroku?

Comment: yes, i have runed `pip freeze` to added to requirements.txt

Answer (score -1):

In general this error means **django-storges** addapter to S3 *(using boto3)* can not load libraries **boto3** or **botocore**

This error raises in runtime then you try use S3 storage first time(or just import **S3Boto3StorageFile** or **S3Boto3Storage**)

To get more details you able to set breakpoint(if you can run debug) at line where exception raise (in you case *line 32 in file s3boto3.py*, in my case the same) and line by line try to import(for example, in evaluate expression if your IDE supports it or in any other way, say running it a python command line and executing the command one by one) what was imported in the code in block **try** until you get **ImportError** - and see details for the reason)

If the method described above is not possible for some reason, you can modify this file(*s3boto3.py*) so that the details of the emitted **ImportError** are printed

In other words, you just need to understand that hapens in this small piece of code, and understand what went wrong with the import, because really throwing here exceptions **ImproperlyConfigured** with the message that `Could not load boto3's S3 bindings.` simply hides the details thrown earlier **ImportError**